# If first line in RichtextBox doesn't contain numbers

Tags: vb.net

I need some kind of code to check if the first line in a richtextbox contains numbers or not.

Something like this:

```
If Richtextbot1.Lines(0) contains Numbers Then
Goto startbot
Else
End If
```

Here is an example of my richtextbox lines:

1. 2245 queen st west, ON, M6R2W7
2. 12 RRw Rd, ON
3. ON, M2N4E3

If the first line contains 4 or more numbers, it will use it. After each loop it will delete line 1. So it repeats for the next line. When my code reaches the 3rd line, and it doesnt find 4 or more numbers it needs to delete the line.

Comment: Horribly vague.  Does "ABC123XYZ" contain a number?  Is there some kind of separation between the 'words'.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate through the characters in the line looking for one that is a digit based on the premise that if you find a digit you'll be able to find what you term a 'number.'

```
Public Function DoesLineContainNumber() As Boolean
    For index As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines(0).Length - 1
        If Char.IsDigit(RichTextBox1.Lines(0)(index)) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

You could then extract these 'numbers' by parsing the string starting with the first digit found.

Comment: Thanks Simon. One more thing though, how can I edit the function so it checks if the line contains 4 or more numbers? I should have mention this in the start.

Comment: You have to define 'number'.  Do you mean single digits like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... or do you mean numbers like 4, 56, 123, 9876, etc...  Do you mean decimal, hexadecimal, octal or some other base of number?  Can these be floating point numbers like 1.23, 7.21e-3, etc...?  Once you define what you mean by number then you can write a parser or perhaps even a regex expression to determine how many 'number' there are in the line.

Comment: Here is an example of my richtextbox lines:
LINE1:2245 queen st west, ON, M6R2W7
LINE2:12 RRw Rd, ON, M8R4W5
LINE3:ON, M2N4E3

If the first line contains 4 or more numbers, it will use it. After each loop it will delete line 1. So it repeats for the next line. When my code reaches the 3rd line, and it doesnt find 4 or more numbers it needs to delete the line.

Comment: Do me a favor, add the information in your last comment to the original post.  That way your post will appear back on the active post page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim firstLineContainsNumber As Boolean = ContainsNumber(RichTextBox1.Lines(0))
...

Public Function ContainsNumber(input As String) As Boolean         
    Dim myRegex As New Regex("\d")        
    Return (myRegex.IsMatch(input))        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used matches to check for numbers on the first line and then for each match I added 1 to a count variable:

```
  Dim count As Integer
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(RichTextBox1.Lines(0), "\d")

    For Each m As Match In matches
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            count += 1
        Next
    Next

   If count >= 4 Then
        MsgBox("contains 4 or more numbers")
    End If
```